# Endless loop with two loop functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if my code is okay. The code is working and doing exactly what I want, printing out hello when in_position is true and printing world when in_position = False.
I now want to fill these functions with real code.
But I'm a beginner and prefer to ask, maybe unexpected errors occur there, or it is just unclean when filling with a lot of code.

```
import time

in_position = True

def loop():
    global in_position
    while in_position == True:
        time.sleep(2.4)
        print("Hello") 
        #fill with real code
        in_position = False
        loop_two()
        
        
def loop_two():
    global in_position
    while in_position == False:
        time.sleep(2.4)
        #fill with real code
        print("World")
        in_position = True
        loop()
        
    
    
def main():
    loop()
    loop_two()
    
main()
```

Comment: Maybe tell us more about why you are structuring the code in this way.

Comment: Does the `loop_two()` in `main` ever get called?

Comment: I want to fill the first loop with a web scraper for stock data and the second loop is 
to process these data.

Comment: loop() in main is probably unnecessary, because it always will start with in_position = False

Comment: It's not necessary inside loop_two()! once that while loop exits, the function returns and you're back in loop().
Or more generally, only one needs to call the other. Not both each other.

Comment: @Dmiters you are right, thx a lot.

Comment: It is a weird structure for various reasons. You don't need the global in_position to start with but it might be because this is just a sample. The other problem is that every loop is adding a method call to the stack. After a (long) while, you're going to get a stack overflow error. This code would be a lot better written in a flat loop, possibly calling two independent, not looping, functions to do the actual work.

Answer (score 2):

Main calls `loop()` that then calls `loop_two()` that calls `loop()` ... and it goes again and again in an endless loop calls.
You should put some ending conditions unless you want your code to run forever.

That also means that `loop_two()` is never called in `main()` (nor anything written after the first `loop()` call will be).

Another thing : use of `global` for the `in_position` parameter here doesn't look necessary. It should be more readable to put `in_position` as a parameter of your functions. Something like this :

```
import time

def loop(in_position ):
    while in_position == True:
        time.sleep(2.4)
        print("Hello") 
        #fill with real code
        in_position = False
        loop_two(in_position )
        
        
def loop_two(in_position ):
    while in_position == False:
        time.sleep(2.4)
        #fill with real code
        print("World")
        in_position = True
        loop(in_position )
        
    
    
def main():
    in_position = True
    loop(in_position)
    
main()
```

Comment: Thx a lot, but in_position = False is missing in loop(), or did i missed something?

Comment: Indeed, I've been a bit too lose when deleting some lines. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written in your comment

> I want to fill the first loop with a web scraper for stock data and the second loop is to process these data.

I would suggest you to do something different in your code, and take a look into [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

You may rewrite it this way:

```
# instead of loop_one
def scrape_web():

    scraped_data = your_scraping_function()
    while scraped_data:
        yield scraped_data
        scraped_data = your_scraping_function()

#instead of loop_two    
def process_data(data):
    # here you put your processing algorithm
    processed_data = do_something_with(data)
    
def main():
    for new_data in scrape_web():
        process_data(new_data)
```

This should be much more memory efficient, and IMO cleaner solution. What this code exactly does:

1. Calls `scrape_web` function, and when this function yields new data (you can think of yield as similar to return) then it is saved to `new_data` variable
2. Calls `process_data`, which is handed `new_data` which you scraped earlier
3. After processing data it will again call `scrape_web`, starting from line after yield - so it will call `your_scraping_function` from while loop, and if your_scraping_function return something (e.g. that is not `None`, `False`, empty string) then it will again yield this data, save it to `new_data`, and go back to point 2.

I know this is not exactly answering your first question regarding loops, but based on your comment I thought it might be useful to think different about this particular issue.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Comment: @barny thanks for heads up, I'm not a native english speaker :). I thought it's a verb from 
noun 'scrap' in the meaning of 'piece' (so to break something into pieces). Edited my answer.

Comment: Yes you can have a scrap of fabric, or code, but that's different from scrape/scraping. English is a horrible mixture of different things with different rules, but scraping is about scrape, scraper, scraped.